# Get Re payment from card number already used in authorize.net payment gateway php

Tags: php

I have integrate authorize.net payment gateway with my php application. e.g.

If anyone make payment transaction successfully, then I have saved card number and transactionid in my own database, response generated by authorize.net 
Now my requirment is make a another payment capture transaction from using that card number and transactionid(if needed). using php script.

I have used a url for refund by authorize.net exist card number and transactionid. e.g

`$response = file_get_contents('https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll?x_version=3.1&x_type=CREDIT&x_amount='.$amount.'&x_card_num='.$cardnumber.'&x_delim_data=TRUE&x_relay_response=FALSE&x_login=36h3RAmP5x&x_tran_key=6vtf765Y5mX238Mt&x_trans_id='.$transactionID);`

In this url 
`x_type=CREDIT`

I have used `x_type=AUTH_CAPTURE`

But it gives invalid card number error

Please let me know answer asap.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot save people's credit card numbers in your database....my god...

Comment: Yes you are right, but I am not saving whole credit card number, only last four digits saving for refund payment to that card number.

Any one have answers? Please let me know